# Certain variables assigned by functions are not being assigned in python script

Tags: python, function, variables

I am working on procedural generation of character concepts. As part of this, I have set variables to change the pronouns in text so they will be correct for the generated character. However, for some reason, my code refuses to assign variables for this, resulting in output like "Bob is a Caucasian .  works as..." It should read "Bob is a Caucasian male. He works as..."

Everywhere a pronoun or the word male or female should be, it prints nothing. Not to console, nor to file. When I strip the entire script down to just the code that calls for the function to run, and the function itself, it still wont assign the variables.

Other systems that use functions to assign variables are working 100% fine.

I've rewritten new functions 3 times to try different approaches to this. I've tried making the variables global. I don't know what else to try.

Here is the function.

```py
def pronouns(sex1):
    pronoun1, pronoun1alternate, pronoun2, pronoun2alternate = "", "", "", ""
    if sex1 == "male":
        pronoun1 = "He"
        pronoun1alternate = "he"
        pronoun2 = "His"
        pronoun2alternate = "his"
    elif sex1 == "female":
        pronoun1 = "She"
        pronoun1alternate = "she"
        pronoun2 = "Her"
        pronoun2alternate = "her"
    return pronoun1, pronoun1alternate, pronoun2, pronoun2alternate
```

The variable sex1 is created much later on, and cannot be created within this function as I may want to expand this program for fantasy and sci-fi character concepts later on and decided to handle sex selection with each individual race in case I want to do something like Species-8472 in the future.

Here is how the function called later on.

```py
p1, p1a, p2, p2a = pronouns(sex1)
```

I have been informed that python passes the values but not names. It didn't work when the function outputted p1 p1a and so on either. I was told using different names in the same order might fix the problem. It did not.

Here his how the variables are supposed to be used.

```py
description = name + " is a " + race + " " + sex + ". " + p1 + " has " + eyes + " eyes. " + colorapp
```

It has no problem filling out the name, race, eye color, and the colorapp variable, but cannot ever, regardless of what I do, fill out sex, or any pronoun values.

No error messages occur when this code is run in isolation. It will print blank lines if asked to just print the pronouns or sex. However, sex1 will print successfully, as will almost every other variable in the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you assigning value to variable sex1? Make sure it is passed in lowercase. If this is the problem you can use sex1.lower() on lines 3 and 8 of the function.

Comment: It is being assigned via
```python
    sexes = ["male", "female"]
    chances = [60, 40]
    sex1 = random.choices(sexes, chances)
```

Comment: sex1 = random.choices(sexes, chances) returns a list with one string. You should use **sex1 = random.choices(sexes, chances)[0]** to get the string inside the list.